# Problems with Castle DynamicProxy2 on .Net 3.5 SP1 on Win2003 Server

Tags: nhibernate, windows-server-2003, castle-dynamicproxy

I've an mvc + nh asp.net application. On my dev machine (win 7 Ent) all works fine, if deployed on a Win 2k3 (tried 2 different vm and one phisical machine) I got the following error..

anyone can help? Cannot explain this issue (tried the same build, so i think it'a machine configuration issue)..

Derived method 'set_ID' in type 'CustomerProxy75950979a2a048e889584c21696f7f1b' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' cannot reduce access

[TypeLoadException: Derived method 'set_ID' in type 'CustomerProxy75950979a2a048e889584c21696f7f1b' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' cannot reduce access.]
   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder._TermCreateClass(Int32 handle, Module module) +0
   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock() +915
   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType() +108
   Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.BuildType() +48
   Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateCode(Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options) +3821
   Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options) +84
   Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors) +92
   Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, IInterceptor[] interceptors) +21
   NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactory.GetProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session) +283

Comment: Different security settings on the server than on the development box?

Comment: the app runs on the LocalSystem account in full trust.

Comment: can you check if this works for trunk version of Dynamic Proxy? Please move this discussion to Castle Users group: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users

Answer (score 1):

found the issue. I had a duplicate property in my derived class (same as the base class defined with a template).

Answer (score 0):

just had this error, and again this issue was having a duplicate property of id in my derived classes.